C++ cli list of structs declaration Visual studio 2022
I have C++ non-managed code
namespace CPPWrapperClass {

struct RectSize
{
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct Rect
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};
}

How to declare it as an array in managed code in CLI?
CLI:
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
namespace CLI
{
    public ref class MaxRectsBinPack : public ManagedObject<CPPWrapperClass::MaxRectsBinPack>
    {
        std::vector<CPPWrapperClass::Rect> usedRectangles;//a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type
        List<CPPWrapperClass::Rect> usedRectangles;       //is not a valid generic argument
        How to initialize list of Rect ?
    }
}

How to initialize list of Rect ? Thanks in advance

I usually mirror each native class with a separate C++/CLI one, and add conversion functions that create the managed ones from the native ones. Then you can populate a C++/CLI System::Collections::Generic::List using it.

It would help if you posted a [mre] of your case (with emphasis on minimal). For example: MaxRectsBinPack's deifnition does not appear in the posted code, but on the other hand  at the momoent RectSize is not used and maybe can be omitted.

@wohlstad Hi thanks for your timely response. I have successfully created it using this answer. Now I am checking if the wrapper is accessible from my project. Will come back after that mate
